# variable have not been initialize while I have already did

Tags: java, arrays

The problem is :

> a program prompts the user to enter a list of six positive integers,
>   and then declares an array of six elements. The program should sort
>   the list’s elements in ascending order. In addition, the program
>   should display both the original and the sorted list.

My code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class q2 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String[] args ) {
     int i;
int [] fList = new int [6];
int [] sList = new int [6];

 System.out.println ("Enter 6 positive integers :");

 for ( i=0 ; i<fList.length ;i++)
 fList[i]=scan.nextInt();

  for( i=0 ; i<fList.length ; i++)//to copy
  fList=sList;

 int min;
 {
 for ( i=0;i<sList.length ; i++)//sort
 min = i ; 
  for (int j=i+1 ; i<sList.length ; i++)
  if (sList[j] < sList[min] )
   min=j;

    int temp=sList[i];
    sList[i]=sList[min];
    sList[min]=temp;
 }

 System.out.println("Original array : ");
 for ( i=0 ; i < fList.length ; i++)
 System.out.println(fList[i] + " ");

 System.out.println();
 System.out.println("Array after sorting :");
 for ( i=0 ; i < sList.length ; i++)
 System.out.println(sList[i] + " ");

}
}
```

it says :

> q2.java:23: variable min might not have been initialized   if
>   (sList[j] < sList[min] )
>                          ^ q2.java:27: variable min might not have been initialized     sList[i]=sList[min];
>                          ^ 2 errors

while I have already initialize it

Answer (score 4):

```
int min;
```

You've not initialized the `min`. I can see that you've done `min = i ;` in the `for` loop, but that's still conditional(the `for` may not always execute, say in the case, the array is empty) and that's why the compiler says that. You need to initialize it with a default value

```
int min = 0;
```

or assign some value to it outside any `if` or `for`, or any conditional statement in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
int min;
```

Give it an initial value.

```
int min = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize min inside the `for` loop. The compiler can not know if `sList` is empty or not. If it is empty, then the initialization code will not be run. That's why it is complaining that the variable may not have been initialized.

You should initialize your `min` to some value beforehand.

That begin said, the first for loop after the declaration of `min` does not make any sense: `min` will always be equal to `sList.length-1` then (and `i` will be `sList.length`. You should rethink your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use braces for all blocks even when they're not needed (at the moment) - otherwise it can get unwieldy. Also you don't really need both `i` and `min`, but I left it in.

```
import java.util.*;

public class q2 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int[] fList = new int[6];
        int[] sList = new int[6];

        System.out.println("Enter 6 positive integers :");

        for (i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
            fList[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        //to copy
        for (i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
            fList = sList;
        }

        //sort
        for (i = 0; i < sList.length; i++) {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; i < sList.length; i++) {
                if (sList[j] < sList[min])
                    min = j;

                int temp = sList[i];
                sList[i] = sList[min];
                sList[min] = temp;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Original array : ");
        for (i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(fList[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Array after sorting :");
        for (i = 0; i < sList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(sList[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```